# ECONOMIC VS ACCOUNTIGN PROFIT

Tags: profits

Been trying to calculate economic vs accounting profit as per below but I don't seem to get the correct answer. Any help will be appreciated.

John Smith previously earned £ 10,000 a year in employment and had £ 100,000 invested in government securities, yielding 10% per annum. He sold his securities for £ 100,000 and started his own business. Initially, he rented a factory for £ 5000 per annum, but subsequently purchased
it for £ 20,000, leaving £ 80,000 as the financial capital within the firm.
John Smith’s accountants estimate that total revenue of the firm in the past year was £ 100,000 and total costs were £ 80,000, including a salary of £ 5000 paid to John Smith

[image]

**The Economist**

[image]

Comment: Just to add, the Yield(10%) should it consider 100k(Initial Capital) or 80k(meaning after the purchase of the factory)

Answer (score 1):

Take into account the following identities

$Economic ~ Cost = Accounting Cost + Opportunity Cost$
$Economic~ Profit = Total Revenue - Economic Cost$

In your case the opportunity cost is **(10K-5K)** Salary he gave up plus the 10% yield on 100,000 securities. 
*"10K-5K because he could be earning 10K but now he is earning 5K so he gave up a 5K difference."* 
The 10% should be calculated on 100K because, because that is the amount he could have available if he did not start a business and purchase a factory.

$Economic ~profit = 100,000 - (80,000+5000+10,000) = 5000$